# Write pipe delimited column names in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am using the below query to produce a pipe delimited file but I also want pipe delimited column name. Can you please help me with that.

```
select  cast (sample_dt||'|'||trim(trailing '.' from trim(leading ' ' from acct_id))||'|'||name1||'|'||ent_sub_lob||'|'||app_dt||'|'||home_phn_num||'|'||city_1_name||'|'||geo_st_cd||'|'||surveyid||'|'||study_type||'|'||ent_lob||'|'||channel||'|'||market_C||'|'||merchant_id as char(300))
from  ud.testing;
```

Comment: Instead of all those concats better switch to Teradata's CSV: https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/SQL_Reference/B035-1145-160K/mah1472241143314.html#

Comment: Add to the Teradata CSV a query against the DBC dictionary view ColumnsV to get the column names dynamically.

Comment: Could be easier ones, but dint try this. But thank you for your quick turn around on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you either need a table column name or your current derived column i.e. `cast (sample_dt||'|'||trim(trailing '.' from.....` name as `|` separated. In both cases, you just need double quotes `""` around column name as below.

**In Create Table:**

```
create TABLE t1(
"x1 | y1" char(300)
);
```

You can check created table definition with `show` command.

```
show TABLE t1;

CREATE SET TABLE t1 ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      "x1 | y1" CHAR(300) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)
PRIMARY INDEX ( "x1 | y1" );
```

**In derived column:**

```
SELECT 'abc'||' | '|| 'zyc' as "Test | ABC";

Test | ABC
----------
abc | zyc
```

You current query will become.

```
SELECT CAST (sample_dt||'|'||trim(TRAILING '.'
                                  FROM trim(LEADING ' '
                                            FROM acct_id))||'|'||name1||'|'||ent_sub_lob||'|'||app_dt||'|'||home_phn_num||'|'||city_1_name||'|'||geo_st_cd||'|'||surveyid||'|'||study_type||'|'||ent_lob||'|'||channel||'|'||market_C||'|'||merchant_id AS char(300)) AS "Pipe | Seperated"
FROM ud.testing;
```

Hope it will help :-)